# Since a ruby container upgrade we expirience a lot of: `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError` `SSL_read: unexpected eof while reading` issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, openssl, alpine-linux

So we saw a lot of `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError` `SSL_read: unexpected eof while reading`, when we upgraded our ruby alpine base container image. As far as I understand, the main reason behind our issue, is an included upgrade of openssl from 1.1 to 3. There was some time we downgraded to 1.1. I am not totally sure, how we did that, since it worked for a while - and then not anymore. Most probably at some point we upgraded the openssl gem itself, too. I did not dig deep enough into the "why did the downgrade work for some time and suddenly not anymore" (but this should not be relevant here anyway, since I normally take downgrade for a bad option and we only had chosen that, after our initial research did not give us any results fast enough).

After long digging into how to fix it with openssl 3 (gem and libs) I finally figured, I can get back to old behaviour by setting

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS.merge( 
  options: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:options] + OpenSSL::SSL::OP_IGNORE_UNEXPECTED_EOF 
).freeze
```

(yeah, I should not be proud of overwriting that constant. I tried to do it the least invasive way I could imagine)

We are living with this now. But it feels wrong for me.
So I digged into some of the specific problems. One was about an old custom social media validator, that checks the url for some given social media identifier - and this won't be accessible without oauth authorization anymore. So the unexpected eof there is happening because of authorization issues. That's one of the possible root causes I googled anyway.

But for one of our main issues I could not get nearby the root cause. So we are using active storage with google storage provider for image uploads. I see in our error tracker only a 5 steps deep backtrace that jumps from a middleware directly to openssl/buffering.rb line 80. But the issue seems to happen somewhere in between in `ActiveStorage::Representations::RedirectController#show`. I cannot imagine, that google still is responding with wrong ssl handling (as it was the reason, why openssl had to support ignoring unexpected EOF for so long). But I have no hunch, what we maybe are doing wrong here.

So: Has anyone experienced this issue with active storage + google storage and knows some possible root cause and how I can fix it appropriately (instead of overwriting the default params of `SSLContext`)?

thanks so far

Comment: Sounds like a tricky issue. You might try to reproduce the issue with plain Ruby (no ActiveStorage) or even with cURL. If you can, you can report it as a bug to Google. OTOH, if it is a gem issue, perhaps you can write a PR that sets the `OP_IGNORE_UNEXPECTED_EOF` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to config/initializers something like ssl_patch.rb

```rb
if OpenSSL::SSL.const_defined?(:OP_IGNORE_UNEXPECTED_EOF)
  OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:options] |= OpenSSL::SSL::OP_IGNORE_UNEXPECTED_EOF
end
```